# Refinitiv data in Excel - Retrieve Hang Seng Index

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can easily retrieve the Dow Jones (DJI), German DAX (DAX) or Nasdaq (NASDAQ). But I am unable to find the Hang Seng Index. "HSI" does return unrelated results only.

Comment: Why?  Most likely your data provider is either not carrying that Index, or using a different ticker value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reply on freelance however it is not allowing me to do so. 
Here the issue is data provider. Refinitiv and Nasdaq is the data provider for Excel. If particular index is not in Nasdaq website you can't find the same in Excel. 
This is the issue in this.